# Firebug is permanently inactive

Tags: firebug

Firebug used to work fine -- until something happened -- not sure what. FF 3.6.3 on XP PRo current. The net effect is Firebug is now always inactive. The icon is present and gray as is normal. Click on the icon and I get:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nncc.net](http://nncc.net/StackOverflow/Firebug-notActive.jpg))</sub>

It does this regardless of the site. I've uninstalled Firebug and re-installed. nada. Additionally, the Tools > Firebug menu yields nothing.

The only unusual issue I can think of is it may of stopped working sometime after I created an additional FF profile (which has since been removed) for a test. Somehow, in removing the extra profile, my bookmarks were deleted. I recovered them from by my online-backup service.

Any suggestions?  I'd really like to get the Firebug functionality back.

thanks.

Comment: I think this question can better be asked at [Firebug's discussion groups](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug) or otherwise on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firebug).

Answer (score 1):

Install Firebug in a new Firefox profile.
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ

jjb